# Multiplicar matrices en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, matrices, numpy

Esta es una duda un poco simple pero que no consigo resolverla por mi cuenta, y tampoco he encontrado ningún post relacionado con este tema, mi duda es la siguiente:

```
matriz=[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
print(matriz)

matriz[0]=matriz[0]*2

print(matriz)
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que multiplique por dos cada grid de la fila 0, de tal forma que quede así:

```
matriz=[[2,2,2],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
```

Y no así:

```
matriz=[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

No sería un inconveniente para mi usar numpy, pero no he conseguido solucionar el problema con numpy tampoco.

Un saludo, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con numpy es trivial, de hecho funciona tal como tú lo has escrito. Pero eso sí, tu matriz has de crearla con `numpy.array`, en lugar de con listas python. Así:

```
import numpy as np
matriz= np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
print(matriz)

matriz[0]=matriz[0]*2

print("---------------")
print(matriz)
```

Salida:

```
[[1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]]
---------------
[[2 2 2]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente lo que estás haciendo es esto:

```
print([1,1,1]*2)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

`[1,1,1]` es una lista común de Python, el método `__mul__` o especificamente el `*` cuando haces `[1,1,1]*2` no es una multiplicación aritmética, según la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) para los datos tipo Secuencia (una lista lo es):

> **s * n or n * s**    equivalent to adding s to itself n times

Es decir hacer: `[1,1,1]*2` equivale a replicar `[1,1,1]` dos veces. La forma para lograr la multiplicación, desde una lista de listas de python (matriz) sería hacerlo mediante una comprensión, de la siguiente manera:

```
matriz=[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]

matriz[0] = [a*2 for a in matriz[0]]
print(matriz)
[[2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Pero si en realidad, vas a usar `numpy` la respuesta de abulafia es la adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

NumPy permite hacer esto actualmente usando el operador de asignación `*=`, realizando la operación directamente sobre los elementos del array:

```
import numpy as np

matriz = np.array([[1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1]])

matriz[0] *= 2
```

> ```
> >>> matriz
> array([[2, 2, 2],
>        [1, 1, 1],
>        [1, 1, 1]])
> ```

Con una lista Python tienes varias opciones pero es más engorroso y menos eficiente, por ejemplo:

- Usar un `for` para recorrer la lista y hacer la operación in-place:

  ```
  matriz = [[1,1,1],
            [1,1,1],
            [1,1,1]]


  for i in range(len(matriz[0])):
      matriz[0][i] *= 2
  ```
- Usando compresión de listas:

  ```
  matriz = [[1,1,1],
            [1,1,1],
            [1,1,1]]

  matriz[0] = [n * 2 for n in matriz[0]]
  ```